# Subquestion or sub-question? (British English)

Tags: spelling, hyphens

I'm a non native English speaker writing a dissertation in British English. I'm trying to understand whether I should write the word "subquestion" with or without hyphen.

[This English stackexchange post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/889/when-should-compound-words-be-written-as-one-word-with-hyphens-or-with-spaces) seems to suggest writing it without a hyphen if I understand correctly? However I also took a look at [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=subquestion%2Csub-question&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csubquestion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csub%20-%20question%3B%2Cc0) and it suggest the hyphened version is way more common post 2000.

Which would be the best way to spell the word?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sub-question%2C+sub+question%2C+subquestion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csub%20-%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csub%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csubquestion%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hyphen usage changes all the time and it is largely a matter of style. I like the hyphen and would use *sub-question* in this case. See this BBC article: [Small object of grammatical desire](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/magazine/7004661.stm). Until you have developed your own preferences (and learned when hyphens are really necessary), buy a good dictionary and stick to its recommendations. Opinions differ, so if you just search for recommendations on-line, your hyphenation will be all over the place. Alternatively, always use the same on-line dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got confused in the first place because I was using multiple contradicting sources. I'll stick to one source and just follow it's style from now on.

Comment: "On-line"? Really?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the  recommendation  of whatever style guide your university or dissertation chair allows or requires.